# Wpf Button Width Based On Window Size

Tags: .net, wpf

I have stackpanel with three buttons.. like below

```
 <stackpanel orientation="Horizontal">
    <Button Content="btnone" width="100" height="50"/>
    <Button Content="btntwo" width="100" height="50"/>
    <Button Content="btnthree" width="100" height="50"/>
</stackpanel>
```

when i change the window size the buttons will be resized to cover entire window width.. Assume that currently my window width is 300.. Kindly help me..

Answer (score 3):

A `Grid` panel would probably be more appropriate here than a `StackPanel`.  If I understand your question correctly, then this will do what you want:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Button Content="One" Grid.Column="0" Height="50" Margin="10"/>
    <Button Content="Two" Grid.Column="1"  Height="50" Margin="10"/>
    <Button Content="Three" Grid.Column="2" Height="50" Margin="10"/>
</Grid>
```

[image]

Comment: Actually i have that stackpanel in first row of the grid.. B.K

Comment: @A.Manikandan And?  You can place a Grid inside that row, instead of a StackPanel.  I'm just telling you that what you want to achieve will be a lot harder with a StackPanel.  I don't know your entire layout, as you have not provided it in your question.

Comment: @A.Manikandan No problem.